# RegExp get concurrent lines with characters at same index

Tags: javascript, regex

I have several lines of text as one variable:

```
AAbcd
bAAcd
bcAAd
cbAAd
AbcdA
Abccd

OR

var str = "AAbcd\nbAAcd\nbcAAd\ncbAAd\nAbcdA\nAbccd"
```

I want to get the two lines where "AA" appear in the same index of their respective lines, so long as those lines are concurrent.

The first line `AAbcd` has a different index than the second line `bAAcd` and wouldn't match.

Line 3 and 4 (`bcAAd` and `cbAAd`) would match, since they both start at index 2 and are concurrent.

Is this possible with a single RegExp, or does it require a javascript workaround?

**to clarify**

The return from `var i = RegExp(?).exec(str)` would be "AAd\ncbAA", and I'd really just be interested in the index of this string, which would of course be `i.index`.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you actually want.  "relative to the beginning of the string as a whole."  Which string?  The entire thing or each line?  The content you provided has no matches at all if it's based on the first line.

Comment: @ExplosionPills Update, hopefully it's clearer. Thinking about RegExp always gets my brain in a knot.

Comment: We're getting there, but I'm still not sure what should be returned based on the above input

Comment: Use `split` to string by `\n` then perfomr for loop to check if two AA comes in same index

Comment: @ExplosionPills How's that?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution to your problem:

```
function findWithSameIndex(strings, toFind) {
    var results = {};

    for(var i = 0, length = strings.length; i !== length; i++) {
        var index = strings[i].search(toFind);

        if(index !== -1) {
            if(results[index] !== undefined) {
                return [results[index], i];
            } else {
                results[index] = i;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
};
```

With this function you can do what you want:

```
var strings = ["AAbcd", "bAAcd", "bcAAd", "cbAAd", "AbcdA", "Abccd"];

// two A in sequence
findWithSameIndex(strings, "AA");

// two characters in sequence
findWithSameIndex(strings, /(.)\1/);
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I'm really looking for a RegExp only solution for clarity, but I'll leave this up here for anyone who comes along who may need it.